# Tomcat 8 catalina is not starting

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm working in redhat 7

I have set the JAVA variable in /root/.bashrc :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/jre

export CATALINA_BASE=/www/tomcat/iot
export CATALINA_HOME=/www/tomcat/iot
export CATALINA_TMPDIR=/www/tomcat/iot/temp
```

When i execute this

> ./catalina.sh run

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /www/tomcat/iot
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /www/tomcat/iot
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /www/tomcat/iot/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /www/tomcat/iot/bin/bootstrap.jar:/www/tomcat/iot/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
./catalina.sh: line 366: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

The JRE_HOME don't point in the same path

Comment: As which user do you execute ./catalina.sh run?

Comment: @Henry , I run it as a root user

Comment: Run the bashrc file by calling source ~/.bashrc

Comment: *Never* attempt to run an internet-facing server as root. Not even during development. Besides, reading "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory", what question does this error message leave open?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script named setenv.sh in the folder CATALINA_BASE/bin, if it does not exist already.

Add this line to setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/
```

Make it executable.